# Handle unknown number of columns while pandas csv read

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I got the data from `stdin` like

```
x
x
x    y
x
x    y    z
...
```

and I want to create `pandas DataFrame` based on that input

```
df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep='\t', header=None)
```

, but the problem here is that my data on third line has more values than the first one and I got

> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

The questions is: How can I handle this error when I don't know the longest elements chain(separated by `\t`).

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to clean your data first. Read your file using `open('filename.csv')`, iterate through each line and split by `\t`. That'll yield a list - append each of these lists into a list, and you'll have something like `[ ['x'], ['x'], ['x', 'y'], ['x'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ...]` . Then, just use the default DataFrame constructor  `pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists)` passing this list of lists as arguments

Comment: You can define a large amout of expected fields with the names argument and then dropna. 
`df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep='\t', header=None, names=np.arange(10)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole task can be performed in a **single** instruction,
without any counting of elements in each row.

I prepared such an example reading from a string, using *io.StringIO*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ ln.rstrip().split('\t') for ln in
    io.StringIO(txt).readlines() ]).fillna('')
```

The list comprehension converts each source line into a list
of fragments (between *Tab*s).

Then this list comprehension is the *data* parameter to *pd.DataFrame*
and note that such a list of rows can contain rows of different length.

I added also *fillna('')* to convert each *NaN* into an empty string
(you are free to delete it if you wish).

To run the test, I defined the source variable as:

```
txt = '''x
x
x   y
x
x   y   z
x
x   y   z   v'''
```

end executed the above code, getting:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  x         
1  x         
2  x  y      
3  x         
4  x  y  z   
5  x         
6  x  y  z  v
```

In the target version, replace reading from a string with reading from
*stdin*.